# Adding subview from GUI to custom class using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gui-builder

I'm using netbeans and its GUI Builder.

I have a Form JFrameTest. I created a PersonPanel JPanel class.
I dragged-dropped it into the JFrameTest created by Netbeans. 
So the JFrameTest used by Netbeans contains auto-generated code.

What I want is to add for example a JTable to my custom PersonPanel JPanel class and have the JTable code inside. But now, when I'm dragging Swing subviews like JTable inside my custom class, the code is always generated in the JFrameTest class created by Netbeans.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Learn java and start coding instead of using auto-generated code !

Comment: I'm already investing myself on something I like. I don't want to invest a lot of time into it.

Comment: With that kind of answer "I don't want to invest a lot of time into it" you might as well give up because Java is an interesting language and investing in it is not a waste of time.

Comment: Sure, I don't doubt :]

Comment: Create a new `JPanel Form` add your table to it..In the `JFrame Form` add the `JPanel Form` using `SetContentPane` function